# How to open multiple Openlayers Map in multiple tab of 1 page

Tags: javascript, openlayers

```js
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: 'white'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
       color: '#319FD3',
       width: 1
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
  font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
   color: '#000'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: '#fff',
   width: 3
  })
    })
});


// State
var state = 'state-map';
// style for Ols
var vectorLayerstate = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/openlayers/master/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
 }),
 style: function(feature) {
  style.getText().setText(feature.get('DIST_NAME'));
  return style;
 }
});
var statemap = new ol.Map({
 layers: [
   new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.OSM()
   }),
   vectorLayerstate
 ],
 target: state,
 view: new ol.View({
   center: ol.proj.transform([85.0985, 20.9517], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
   zoom: 6
 })
});
var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: 'green',
  width: 1
 }),
 fill: new ol.style.Fill({
  color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
 }),
 text: new ol.style.Text({
  font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'green'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'green',
      width: 3
    })
 })
});
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    map: statemap,
    style: function(feature) {
     highlightStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('DIST_NAME'));
     return highlightStyle;
    }
 });
var highlight;
  var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

    var feature = statemap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
      return feature;
    });
   
    if (feature !== highlight) {
      if (highlight) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
      }
      if (feature) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
      }
      highlight = feature;
    }

  };
statemap.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
 if (evt.dragging) {
  return;
 }
 var pixel = statemap.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
 displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});
statemap.on('click', function(evt) {
 displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
});
// update map size
statemap.updateSize();







// District
var district = 'district-map';
// style for Ols
var vectorLayerdistrict = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/openlayers/master/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
 }),
 style: function(feature) {
  style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
  return style;
 }
});
var districtmap = new ol.Map({
 layers: [
   new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.OSM()
   }),
   vectorLayerdistrict
 ],
 target: district,
 view: new ol.View({
   center: ol.proj.transform([85.0985, 20.9517], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
   zoom: 6
 })
});

// Block
var block = 'block-map';
// style for Ols
var vectorLayerblock = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/openlayers/master/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
 }),
 style: function(feature) {
  style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
  return style;
 }
});
var blockmap = new ol.Map({
 layers: [
   new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.OSM()
   }),
   vectorLayerblock
 ],
 target: block,
 view: new ol.View({
   center: ol.proj.transform([85.0985, 20.9517], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
   zoom: 6
 })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><section class="content">
        <!-- Page come here -->
        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#state" data-toggle="tab" class="tabs">State Level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#district" data-toggle="tab" class="tabs">District Level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#block" data-toggle="tab" class="tabs">Block Level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <!-- State Level -->
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="state">
                            <section id="new">
                                <h4 class="page-header">State</h4>
                                <div id="state-map" class="map"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /#State -->

                        <!-- District Level-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="district">
                            <section id="new">
                                <h4 class="page-header">District</h4>
                                <div id="district-map" class="map"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /District -->

                        <!-- Block Level-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="block">
                            <section id="new">
                                <h4 class="page-header">Block</h4>
                                <div id="block-map" class="map"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Block -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I have 1 page with 3 tabs called State, District and Block. Each tab has 1 map. Initially State tab is active and the map is visible and the effect whatever I applied to map.

This is my Html for Multiple tab.

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#state" data-toggle="tab" class="tabs">State Level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#district" data-toggle="tab" class="tabs">District Level</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#block" data-toggle="tab" class="tabs">Block Level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <!-- State Level -->
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="state">
                            <section id="new">
                                <h4 class="page-header">State</h4>
                                <div id="state-map" class="map"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /#State -->

                        <!-- District Level-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="district">
                            <section id="new">
                                <h4 class="page-header">District</h4>
                                <div id="district-map" class="map"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /District -->

                        <!-- Block Level-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="block">
                            <section id="new">
                                <h4 class="page-header">Block</h4>
                                <div id="block-map" class="map"></div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Block -->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/openlayers/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/openlayers/ol.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabs").on("click",function(){
        var cur_tab = $(this).attr('href');
        var cur_tab_id = cur_tab.slice(1);
        $("#"+cur_tab_id+"-map").find(".ol-unselectable").css("display:block");
    });
});
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'white'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#319FD3',
        width: 1
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 3
        })
    })
});


// State
var state = 'state-map';
// style for Ols
var vectorLayerstate = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: '../DATA/State.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
        style.getText().setText(feature.get('DIST_NAME'));
        return style;
    }
});
var statemap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayerstate
    ],
    target: state,
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([85.0985, 20.9517], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 6
    })
});
var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'green',
        width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'green'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'green',
            width: 3
        })
    })
});
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    map: statemap,
    style: function(feature) {
        highlightStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('DIST_NAME'));
        return highlightStyle;
    }
 });
var highlight;
  var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

    var feature = statemap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
      return feature;
    });

    if (feature !== highlight) {
      if (highlight) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
      }
      if (feature) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
      }
      highlight = feature;
    }

  };
statemap.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
    }
    var pixel = statemap.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});
statemap.on('click', function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
});
// update map size
statemap.updateSize();







// District
var district = 'district-map';
// style for Ols
var vectorLayerdistrict = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: '../DATA/Odisha_Dist.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
        style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
        return style;
    }
});
var districtmap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayerdistrict
    ],
    target: district,
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([85.0985, 20.9517], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 6
    })
});
districtmap.updateSize();

// Block
var block = 'block-map';
// style for Ols
var vectorLayerblock = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: '../DATA/Odisha_Block.json',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
        style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
        return style;
    }
});
var blockmap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayerblock
    ],
    target: block,
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([85.0985, 20.9517], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 6
    })
});
blockmap.updateSize();
$(".tabs").on("click",function(){
    var cur_tab = $(this).attr("href").slice(1);
    //console.log("#"+cur_tab+"-map");
    $("#"+cur_tab+"-map").find(".ol-unselectable").css({"display":"block"});
    $("#"+cur_tab+"-map").find(".ol-unselectable").attr({"width":"1475","height":"750"});
});
</script>
```

When I am switching to District or Block Tab it create another object for respective map ids. But it doesn't shows the map. If I firebug the page and close that page then District Block page map shows, again If I switch to Block tab then the page shows a blank page. Again If I open firebug and close it, then it shows. Don't know what to do for this. Is this is a browser issue or what.

Comment: try your projectID.updateSize() after each block show. Its may solve your problem

Comment: Already used that, you can check it in my js file. Didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Ever found a solution to this? I'm seeing similar issues.

Comment: @Jeffrey I separated all tabs into 3 different page. In that way only I was able to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue--when I would click back to a previously working tab w/ OL map...nothing was displayed.  Because nothing was in it--it was an empty `<div>`.

`<div _ngcontent-nqw-c11="" class="map" id="map"></div>`

But I was eventually able to work out a solution and I think it was because I was using the literal `id="map"` in my map div and that there is something global scoped in OL that is causing a conflict.

What fixed it was creating a dynamic id for my map component.

1. Add public property:
   `public mapDivId: string;`
2. Set it in constructor:
   `` this.mapDivId = `map-comp-${this.valueHelper.generateUUID()}`; ``
3. In the template, bind the property to the id of the map `<div>`:
   `<div id="map" [attr.id]="mapDivId"> </div>`

*This was in an Angular 8 app, using OL 6.4.3.*